# Booting ends with blinking caps lock indicator light on a Packard Bell mb87

Tags: capslock

After a clean install of Ubuntu 11.10, I have been faced with a crash several times. When I push the computer's power button,it starts to boot as usual, but suddenly it freezes and all I see is a pink screen and a flashing caps lock indicator light. Is there anybody who knows what to do to prevent this from happening?

- It's a Packard Bell mb87,my graphic card is nvidia geforce 8600 gs and I have installed the system via liveCD.

Comment: Can you provide more information. What type of computer ? What hardware (graphics card)? Did the live (desktop) cd work (did you get a graphical desktop) ??

Comment: its packardbell mb87,my graphic card is nvidia geforce 8600 gs and i have install the system via liveCD.i really dont know what kind of information i should have provided,sorry about that

Comment: not a problem , that is why you were asked for additional information.

Comment: Do you have three indicators or just Caps? I've seen all three indicators blinking only on malfunctioning hardware.

Comment: yes i see three of them,but just the caps lock indicator are blinking

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to loading wrong version of Linux kernel image for a version of Ubuntu.

Try manually removing any unwanted Linux kernel images from /boot directory and do 'update-grub' and then re-boot your machine.

In my case, I first installed 32bit-Ubuntu-11.10 which stored Kernel image 3.0.0-14 in /boot directory. Later I installed 64bit-Ubuntu-11.10, which needed kernel image 3.0.0-12. But the grub selected the wrong version of kernel 3.0.0-14, which is configured for 32bit CPU to boot 64-bit Ubuntu 11.10.

As soon as I removed the kernel images of 3.0.0-14 and updated the grub, I got successful boot every time. Just give a try.